# regexp, how to find strings that don't contain a certain character?

Tags: php, regex

i have this set of characters:

```
peach_addict                              612        
EmailName                                 747        
littefooted@aol  805-582-73             748        
cell is pager number                      762        
(805) Parents Home                        765        
Star 82                                   777          
Moms cell                                 1198       
MOM LISA                                  1223       
LUVMARTIA82OL@AOL.                        1342       
ISABLGUTIRREZ@BAMMDELS                    1349
```

i would like to select every line that does not contain the `@` symbol.

if i do `.+@.+` i will get these lines:

```
littefooted@aol  805-582-73             748
LUVMARTIA82OL@AOL.                        1342       
ISABLGUTIRREZ@BAMMDELS                    1349
```

but i want the other ones. I know that i can use the `^` symbol, but this doesnt work: `[^(.+@.+)]`

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is

`^[^@]*$`

This means:

```
^ - beginning of line
[ - start of character class
^ - any character except the following
] - end of character class
* - 0 or more
$ - end of line
```

I've had good results with the regex tutorials [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: @Patrioticcow, you have to have the multi-line flag, and before I had it on the same line with a period, which was a little confusing.